# SSH Into Linux VM(VMware Fusion) From Another Machine

Tags: networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, vmware-fusion

I currently have a RHEL VM running on my mac. I'm able to ssh to this VM from my mac, but when I attempt to SSH from a different machine( different laptop, iPad etc..) I'm unable to connect. How would I go about making my VM accessible from external devices that are not my mac?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the VM configured to use bridged networking?

Comment: Currently, no. Its configured for NAT.